# How do I output the first character of all strings that are in a list?

Tags: python, list

*For example if I have the list:*

['Bob\n', "Joe\n", "Frank\n", "Bill"]

*and want to get the output*

B
J
F
B

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
inp = ["Bob\n", "Joe\n", "Frank\n", "Bill"]
output = '\n'.join([x[0] for x in inp])
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
B
J
F
B
```

Answer (score 3):

use `[]` operator to print first character of `string`

```
l = ['Bob\n', "Joe\n", "Frank\n", "Bill"]
for s in l:
    print(s[0])
```

### output:

```
B
J
F
B
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp = ['Bob\n', "Joe\n", "Frank\n", "Bill"]
print([i[0] for i in tmp])
```